# Play framework: large string in form

Tags: playframework

On my play based website i have a form with a textarea. The text in this field can be very long (>400.000 chars). In this case play resets the form instead of processing. Everything works fine for smaller inputs.

How can i fix this?

My form:

```
[...]
@Constraints.Required
private String input;
[...]
```

It fails in this line:

```
Form<FormWithLargeString> f = form(FormWithLargeString.class).bindFromRequest();
```

Comment: Adding something like `parsers.text.maxLength=500K` to `application.conf` helps?

Comment: if that answered your question please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default maximum content length (in Play 2.3 atleast) is 100Kb, which is too small for the data you are receiving.

You can increase that value adding in your `application.conf`

```
parsers.text.maxLength=500K # adjust the value to your needs.
```

or you can increase it to only a specific method:

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = Your.BodyParser.Impl.class, maxLength = 500 * 1024)
public static Result doSomething() {
    // (...)
}
```